# Cakephp 2 Js->submit () doesn't send any data

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

This the code I am using to submit form via ajax.

```
<?$data = $this->Js->get('#form_emp')->serializeForm(
                                            array(
                                            'isForm' => true,
                                            'inline' => true)
                                        );?>
<?php echo $this->Js->submit('submit.png',
array(
    'url' =>'/employees/update_details',
    'update' => '#update_here', 
                'data'=>$data,
                'async' => false,
               'dataExpression'=>true,
                'method' => 'POST'


                ));
 echo $this->Form->end();
```

When I am doing a debug on the action post data is displayed as empty.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('onclick'=>'post_data(); return false;')) ?>
```

- return false is declared there so the button don't fire and submit/refresh the page

And then in your javascript file (or in the view if you like)

```
function post_data(){
   var formData = $('#form_emp').serialize();
   $.ajax({
       url: '/employees/update_details/',
       type: 'post',
       data: formData,
       success: function(response){
           alert('success');
       }
}
```